# Showing HTML5 Video with a loading GIF image if the video is loading (buffering)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So the HTML5 video has no controls. Basically I want to show a loading gif that shows over the video only when the video is loading (buffering and paused)

```
<video id="myvideo" width="100%"><source src="video/Good.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="movie.html" type="video/ogg"></video>
```

Comment: Check out this thread
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759981/detect-when-video-is-buffering-if-so-display-gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759981/detect-when-video-is-buffering-if-so-display-gif)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect when video is buffering, if so display gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759981/detect-when-video-is-buffering-if-so-display-gif)

Answer (score 0):

How about using the built-in browser animation instead of a gif.
All you have to do is set the controls to TRUE and then back to FALSE depending on the buffering state.
The best practice for me looks like this,

```
<video src="myVideo.fileExtension" onplaying="hideControls(this)" onwaiting="showControls(this)" preload="auto" poster="myAnimatedWebpOrGifThatSaysVideoIsNotYetReady.fileExtension">No video support?</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
//We hide the video control buttons and the playhead when the video is playing and enjoyed by the viewer
function hideControls(event){ event.controls=false; }
//If the video has to pause and wait for data from the server we let controls be seen if the user hovers or taps on the video. As a bonus this also makes the built-in loading animation of the browser appear e.g. the rotating circular shape and we give it a little delay (like 1 sec) because I would say it looks and feels better.
function showControls(event){ setTimeout(function(){ event.controls=true; },1000); }
</script>
```

Maybe you could use `ontimeupdate` instead of `onplaying` which would fire continuously.
As for the delay time actually not 1 but 4 seconds -to me- is the best.